# Inspiration on how to build a great command line interface

Tags: language-agnostic, command-line, user-interface

I am in the process of building interactive front-ends to a
distributed application which to date has been used to run workloads
that had a batch-job like structures and needed no UI at all. The application is mostly written in Perl and C and runs on a mix of Unix and Windows machines, but I think this isn't relevant to the UI.

The first such frontend is going have a command-line user interface --
currently, I envision something similar to the CLIs of the Procurve
switches and Cisco routers that I have worked with.

Like modern network gear CLIs, commands are going to resemble
simple sentences, (i.e. `show vlans ports 1-4`) and the CLI will
have some implicit state, much in the way that Unix shells and
`cmd.exe` in Windows have environment variables and current working
directories. Moreover, I'd like to implement great tab completion that
is aware of the application's state as much as possible and I want to be able to do that with as
little application-*specific* code as possible.

The low-level functionality (terminal I/O) seems easy to implement on
top of GNU Readline or similar libraries, but that's only where the
real fun starts. So far I have looked at the Perl modules
[`Term::Shell`](http://search.cpan.org/~neilw/Term-Shell-0.02/lib/Term/Shell.pod)
and
[`Term::ShellUI`](http://search.cpan.org/~bronson/Term-ShellUI-0.86/lib/Term/ShellUI.pm),
but I'm not convinced that I want to use either of them. I am still
considering rolling my own solution and at the moment I am primarily looking for
inspiration.

Can you recommend any application or library, regardless of
implementation language, that implements a good CLI from which I can
borrow ideas?

Comment: I don't know about inspiration, but I intensely dislike the CLI of Cisco switches. Sure, it has that nifty auto-complete feature, but that feature is basically the only online help there is, and it's not nearly enough. Also, the output is often quite hard to parse, which makes it hard to script -- sort of obviating the entire point of having a CLI in the first place.

Comment: Noted. Unlike Cisco switches, I expose the complete API of my app, so there's not going to be any need for `expect` scripting.

Comment: Who is your target audiance? Are they very technical and used to CLI?

Comment: tathamr: yes, "technical" in the sense that they are not scared of CLIs. That's why I'm going for a CLI first.

Comment: Igor: Thanks for making me realize that I actually *do* see the command line completion as a sort of intuitive (option-limiting) online help.

Comment: How much time/money do you have to spend on this? Personally I would write it in python as noted below because of the packages available and easy transition of code between unix and windows.

Comment: "Unlike Cisco switches, I expose the complete API of my app, so there's not going to be any need for expect scripting."

I'm not sure you should count on that. Obviously I'm not sure about your specific applications, but someone somewhere in the future might just need to use your tools automatically (for testing other systems, for example?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having a look at libcli :

> "Libcli provides a shared library for
>   including a Cisco-like command-line
>   interface into other software."

[http://code.google.com/p/libcli/](http://code.google.com/p/libcli)

BTW - I forgot to mention that it is GNU Lesser GPL and actually used by Cisco in some products.

Comment: The idea of a tree structure as it is described in the README file resonates with my desire to condense the vocabulary into as little code as possible. +1

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at the philosophy underlying [Microsoft PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). From the idea of piping typed objects between commands to the consistency of its commands and argument syntax, I think it can be a source of inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

As for your last sentence/question, I'm particularly fond of zsh completion and line editing (zle).